# Refresh repo on a ubuntu server when master branch on GitHub is updated. How can I do this?

Tags: git, docker, github, server, docker-compose

So I'm running a **docker container** on a ubuntu server. I have bind mount enabled, so when files are changed on the server, it also changes in the running container, that's cool!

I've git cloned the repo from GitHub on to my ubuntu server.

**But now I want an even better development workflow.**

Each time I merge another branch with my master branch or I edit the master directly, I push my code to GitHub.

Then, I connect to my ubuntu server via SSH and go to the repo, then with a simple "git pull" I collect the updated version of my master branch on GitHub. And everything is updated on the server.

> But what I want, is that the repo on the server **listens for changes** on
>   the repo (master) on GitHub. When the master branch on GitHub changes,
>   I want the server to **update** (or better said, pull the master branch
>   from GitHub).

How can I achieve such structure? If the listening part is not possible, should I push to two git repositories (GitHub and the server)? Is that even possible since the repo on the server is a clone? If so, how should I do this.

I appreciate all the help.

Comment: An automation tool like Chef or Ansible can do the code push and restart your remote server, and that can be triggered by your CI system on a successful build.  This is literally exactly the same workflow you’d have if Docker wasn’t involved; I don’t think you’re really getting much value from Docker with this setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, I've used Jenkins. Jenkins is a large tool with lots of functions, one function let Jenkins listen on Webhooks send out by GitHub when the master (or any other branch) changes. Then it will auto pull.

This workflow is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

GitHub provides webhooks which can be used to get an HTTP POST request to a given endpoint when certain events occur, such as a push. You can read more about this at the [GitHub webhook documentation](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/). You can then create a job that, when it receives a notification, does something like this:

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master # works better than pull if you force-push
git submodule update --init    # only if you have submodules
```

That does, however, require that you have a service that listens for webhook requests and checks things out. If you don't want to do that, you can simply push to the remote server. You'll want to set `receive.denyCurrentBranch` to `updateInstead` on the server side, which will ensure that the checkout occurs even though the branch is already checked out.